# Trying to Workout how-to run a Ruby (Sinatra) app on the Ebb webserver

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I need to write a super fast Ruby application to process web requests on Sinatra - and want to run it on the [Ebb webserver](http://ebb.rubyforge.org/).  But I cannot work out how to do this.  Could someone please help me?

Comment: Do not use Ebb, it's not maintained. Patches are ignored and the implementation is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at Rack: http://rack.rubyforge.org/
It's pretty easy really, you have a .ru file which instructs Rack how to start your application, and in your application you have a 'call' method which is called on each request, and sends the response back to Rack.

In my_app.ru

```
require 'my_app'
require 'ebb'

# Rack config
use Rack::Static, urls: ['/js', '/public', '/index.html']
use Rack::ShowExceptions

# Run application
run MyApp.new
```

In my_app.rb

```
class MyApp
 def call env
    request  = Rack::Request.new env
    response = Rack::Response.new
    params = request.params

    response.body = "Hello World"
    response['Content-Length'] = response.body.size.to_s
    response.finish
  end
end
```

Then you specify the .ru file in your sinatra config, like:

```
rackup: my_app.ru
```

Comment: I dont see how the sinatra bit falls into this....where is the sinatra code? In my_app.ru?

Comment: It also turns out that ebb isnt available on Windows...does the same process apply to lighttpd?

Comment: If you're looking for a high-performance server, Nginx is pretty popular for Ruby apps these days, and I've seen it beat Lighttpd in tests.

Comment: but they're not available for Windows are they? :(

Answer (score 2):

sinatra has a -s option to specify a handler. try running your app with -s ebb.